# iOS large title not working with background view behind the scrollView

Tags: ios

I'm using large titles, in the main view I have a scrollView and a view behind the scrollView that is a background image. When I do this, large titles doesn't work (are always big while you scroll) because the scrollView is not the first element inside the main view. If I change the order, the background image covers the scroll view.

Any solutions? Thanks!!

Comment: You need to give some more content in your question.. Like large title is used on what? Any screenshots or pieces of code would be helpful in identifying? Be more concise on what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, I moved the background view inside the scroll view and I attached to the main view with constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the scrollview first then your background, and swap the zPosition of the 2 views.

```
view.addSubviews([scrollView, background])
scrollView.layer.zPosition = 1
background.layer.zPostion = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your Image View inside ScrollView content view. Using constraints pin ImageView to top, bottom, trailing and leading edges of SafeArea(second image).

[image]
[image]